# Mounting VFS error : mount: /fwd: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, mount, vfs

I am trying to mount VFS in Linux, But its giving me this error

> Mount: /fwd: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

It looks like its giving me error that I have messed up with my structures for superblock.

`sudo demsg output`

> [25665.303994] bad magic number

> [25665.303998] error reading buffer_head

> [25665.303998] bad block size

I mounted with `abc# mount test_###.ko /fwd`
Full code of modue in following

```
    #include <linux/init.h>
    #include <linux/fs.h>
    #include <linux/pagemap.h>
    #include <linux/highmem.h>
    #include <linux/time.h>
    #include <linux/string.h>
    #include <linux/backing-dev.h>
    #include <linux/ramfs.h>
    #include <linux/sched.h>
    #include <linux/parser.h>
    #include <linux/magic.h>
    #include <linux/slab.h>
    #include <asm/uaccess.h>
    #include <linux/proc_fs.h>
    #include <linux/pci.h>

    #define RAMFS_DEFAULT_MODE  0755


    /*
    int pci_mmap_fits(struct pci_dev *pdev, int resno, struct vm_area_struct *vma,
              enum pci_mmap_api mmap_api);*/
    extern ssize_t generic_file_splice_write(struct pipe_inode_info *,
                                     struct file *, loff_t *, size_t, unsigned int);
    extern ssize_t do_sync_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *ppos);
    const struct address_space_operations ramfs_aops = {
        .readpage   = simple_readpage,
        .write_begin    = simple_write_begin,
        .write_end  = simple_write_end,

    };

    const struct file_operations ramfs_file_operations = {

        .read   = generic_read_dir,


        .mmap       = generic_file_mmap,
        .fsync      = noop_fsync,


        .llseek     = generic_file_llseek,
    };

    const struct inode_operations ramfs_file_inode_operations = {
        .setattr    = simple_setattr,
        .getattr    = simple_getattr,
    };

    static const struct super_operations ramfs_ops;
    static const struct inode_operations ramfs_dir_inode_operations;

    static struct backing_dev_info ramfs_backing_dev_info = {
        .name       = "ramfs",
        .ra_pages   = 0,    /* No readahead */
        .capabilities   = NOMMU_MAP_DIRECT | NOMMU_MAP_COPY |
                      NOMMU_MAP_READ     | NOMMU_MAP_EXEC    | NOMMU_MAP_WRITE  ,
    };
    //*************************************************Functons*************************************************************

    enum pci_mmap_api {
        PCI_MMAP_SYSFS,  //mmap on /sys/bus/pci/devices/<BDF>/resource<N>
        PCI_MMAP_PROCFS  //mmap on /proc/bus/pci/<BDF>
    };
    int pci_mmap_fits(struct pci_dev *pdev, int resno, struct vm_area_struct *vmai,
              enum pci_mmap_api mmap_api);
    struct pci_filp_private {
        enum pci_mmap_state mmap_state;
        int write_combine;
    };

    static int proc_bus_pci_mmap(struct file *file, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
    {
        struct pci_dev *dev = PDE_DATA(file_inode(file));
        struct pci_filp_private *fpriv = file->private_data;
        int i, ret;

        if (!capable(CAP_SYS_RAWIO))
        return -EPERM;

        /* Make sure the caller is mapping a real resource for this device */
        for (i = 0; i < PCI_ROM_RESOURCE; i++) {
        if (pci_mmap_fits(dev, i, vma,  PCI_MMAP_PROCFS))
            break;
        }

        if (i >= PCI_ROM_RESOURCE)
        return -ENODEV;
        int bars = pci_select_bars(dev, IORESOURCE_MEM);
      /*  ret = pci_mmap_page_range(dev,bars, vma,
                          fpriv->mmap_state,
                          fpriv->write_combine);
      */  if (ret < 0)
        return ret;

        return 0;
    }
    struct inode *ramfs_get_inode(struct super_block *sb,
                          const struct inode *dir, umode_t mode, dev_t dev)
    {
        struct inode * inode = new_inode(sb);

        if (inode) {
        inode->i_ino = get_next_ino();
        inode_init_owner(inode, dir, mode);
        inode->i_mapping->a_ops = &ramfs_aops;

        mapping_set_gfp_mask(inode->i_mapping, GFP_HIGHUSER);
        mapping_set_unevictable(inode->i_mapping);
        /*inode->i_atime = inode->i_mtime = inode->i_ctime = CURRENT_TIME;*/
        switch (mode & S_IFMT) {
            default:
            init_special_inode(inode, mode, dev);
            break;
            case S_IFREG:
            inode->i_op = &ramfs_file_inode_operations;
            inode->i_fop = &ramfs_file_operations;
            break;
            case S_IFDIR:
            inode->i_op = &ramfs_dir_inode_operations;
            inode->i_fop = &simple_dir_operations;

            /* directory inodes start off with i_nlink == 2 (for "." entry) */
            inc_nlink(inode);
            break;
            case S_IFLNK:
            inode->i_op = &page_symlink_inode_operations;
            break;
        }
        }
        return inode;
    }

    /*
     * File creation. Allocate an inode, and we're done..
     */
    /* SMP-safe */
    static int
    ramfs_mknod(struct inode *dir, struct dentry *dentry, umode_t mode, dev_t dev)
    {
        struct inode * inode = ramfs_get_inode(dir->i_sb, dir, mode, dev);
        int error = -ENOSPC;

        if (inode) {
        d_instantiate(dentry, inode);
        dget(dentry);   /* Extra count - pin the dentry in core */
        error = 0;
        /*dir->i_mtime = dir->i_ctime = CURRENT_TIME;*/
        }
        return error;
    }

    static int ramfs_mkdir(struct inode * dir, struct dentry * dentry, umode_t mode)
    {
        int retval = ramfs_mknod(dir, dentry, mode | S_IFDIR, 0);
        if (!retval)
        inc_nlink(dir);
        return retval;
    }

    static int ramfs_create(struct inode *dir, struct dentry *dentry, umode_t mode, bool excl)
    {
        return ramfs_mknod(dir, dentry, mode | S_IFREG, 0);
    }

    static int ramfs_symlink(struct inode * dir, struct dentry *dentry, const char * symname)
    {
        struct inode *inode;
        int error = -ENOSPC;

        inode = ramfs_get_inode(dir->i_sb, dir, S_IFLNK|S_IRWXUGO, 0);
        if (inode) {
        int l = strlen(symname)+1;
        error = page_symlink(inode, symname, l);
        if (!error) {
            d_instantiate(dentry, inode);
            dget(dentry);
            /*dir->i_mtime = dir->i_ctime = CURRENT_TIME;*/
        } else
            iput(inode);
        }
        return error;
    }

    static const struct inode_operations ramfs_dir_inode_operations = {
        .create     = ramfs_create,
        .lookup     = simple_lookup,
        .link       = simple_link,
        .unlink     = simple_unlink,
        .symlink    = ramfs_symlink,
        .mkdir      = ramfs_mkdir,
        .rmdir      = simple_rmdir,
        .mknod      = ramfs_mknod,
        .rename     = simple_rename,
    };

    static const struct super_operations ramfs_ops = {
        .statfs     = simple_statfs,
        .drop_inode = generic_delete_inode,

    };

    struct ramfs_mount_opts {
        umode_t mode;
    };

    enum {
        Opt_mode,
        Opt_err
    };

    static const match_table_t tokens = {
        {Opt_mode, "mode=%o"},
        {Opt_err, NULL}
    };

    struct ramfs_fs_info {
        struct ramfs_mount_opts mount_opts;
    };

    static int ramfs_parse_options(char *data, struct ramfs_mount_opts *opts)
    {
        substring_t args[MAX_OPT_ARGS];
        int option;
        int token;
        char *p;

        opts->mode = RAMFS_DEFAULT_MODE;

        while ((p = strsep(&data, ",")) != NULL) {
        if (!*p)
            continue;

        token = match_token(p, tokens, args);
        switch (token) {
            case Opt_mode:
            if (match_octal(&args[0], &option))
                return -EINVAL;
            opts->mode = option & S_IALLUGO;
            break;
            /*
             * We might like to report bad mount options here;
             * but traditionally ramfs has ignored all mount options,
             * and as it is used as a !CONFIG_SHMEM simple substitute
             * for tmpfs, better continue to ignore other mount options.
             */
        }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    int ramfs_fill_super(struct super_block *sb, void *data, int silent)
    {
        struct ramfs_fs_info *fsi;
        struct inode *inode;
        int err;



        fsi = kzalloc(sizeof(struct ramfs_fs_info), GFP_KERNEL);
        sb->s_fs_info = fsi;
        if (!fsi)
        return -ENOMEM;

        err = ramfs_parse_options(data, &fsi->mount_opts);
        if (err)
        return err;

        sb->s_maxbytes      = MAX_LFS_FILESIZE;
        sb->s_blocksize     = PAGE_SIZE;
        /*sb->s_blocksize_bits    = PAGE_CACHE_SHIFT;*/
        sb->s_magic     = RAMFS_MAGIC;
        sb->s_op        = &ramfs_ops;
        sb->s_time_gran     = 1;

        inode = ramfs_get_inode(sb, NULL, S_IFDIR | fsi->mount_opts.mode, 0);
        sb->s_root = d_make_root(inode);
        if (!sb->s_root)
        return -ENOMEM;

        return 0;
    }

    struct dentry *ramfs_mount(struct file_system_type *fs_type,
                       int flags, const char *dev_name, void *data)
    {
        return mount_nodev(fs_type, flags, data, ramfs_fill_super);
    }
    #define MS_NOUSER   (1<<31)
    static struct dentry *rootfs_mount(struct file_system_type *fs_type,
                               int flags, const char *dev_name, void *data)
    {
        return mount_nodev(fs_type, flags|MS_NOUSER, data, ramfs_fill_super);
    }

    static void ramfs_kill_sb(struct super_block *sb)
    {
        kfree(sb->s_fs_info);
        kill_litter_super(sb);
    }

    static struct file_system_type ramfs_fs_type = {
        .name       = "ramfs3",
        .mount      = ramfs_mount,
        .kill_sb    = ramfs_kill_sb,
        .fs_flags   = FS_USERNS_MOUNT,
    };


    int __init init_ramfs_fs(void)
    {
        return register_filesystem(&ramfs_fs_type);
    }

    module_init(init_ramfs_fs)

    /*
    int __init init_rootfs(void)
    {
        int err;

        err = bdi_init(&ramfs_backing_dev_info);
        if (err)
        return err;

        err = register_filesystem(&rootfs_fs_type);
        if (err)
        bdi_destroy(&ramfs_backing_dev_info);

        return err;
    }




    */
```

Comment: In the command `abc# mount test_xxx.ko /fwd` what character ``#`` means? In a shell this character normally starts the **comment**, so your command is effectively `abc`.

Comment: consider I typed `mount name_of_file.ko /fwd` # is simply command prompt I have set

Comment: The `mount` command mounts a **device**, not a *module*. The **module** is inserted into the kernel with `insmod` command. You need firstly insert module into the kernel. This insertion will register the **filesystem** named "ramfs3". Then perform mount with `-t ramfs3` option, so this mount will use the filesystem you have registered. Note, that if your filesystem requires some device to be specified, then this device should be preliminary **formatted** (filled with the data in appropriate format).

Comment: @Tsyvarev my module is getting loaded but filesystem is not appearing in /proc/mounts. this function `    err = register_filesystem(&minfs_fs_type);` is called without any error but why filesysystem isnt mounting? any idea?

Comment: You misunderstand the concepts. A *filesystem*, which is registered via `register_filesystem`, denotes a way how a device (block device, pseudo-device, etc.) can be interpreted as a hierarchy of files. "Mounting" refers to **devices**: you may mount a device and interpret it as a specific filesystem. Exactly these mounts are performed with `mount` system calls and shown under `/proc/mounts`. You may have several devices mounted and interpreted as a same filesystem. They will use the same filesystem driver but with different data.

Comment: @Tsyvarev `Exactly these mounts are performed with mount system calls and shown under /proc/mounts` I checked my module filesystem is not there so is this means `register_filesystem` is not working for some reason?

Comment: Once again, a filesystem is NOT a mount. `register_filesystem` doesn't modify `/proc/mount`. (`register_filesystem` modifies `/proc/filesystems` instead). For perform a mount, you need to use `mount` utility.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have created a block device. and attached filesystem type to it with mount and when I type `mount...` my module filesystem mount function executes. But the output of `mount...` command is `mount: /lll: /dev/block/fwdabc is not a valid block device.` does it means my block device is not created properly with mknod or is it my file system module that I messed up

Comment: @Tsyvarev also please explain what difference there is between mounting to device and mmap to memory. when I mmap does it mount or do I need to mount first to mmap to memory and can I only mmap to memory in device address space or anywhere in memory even some other place where special block device address space not exists -- outside like some io memory?

Comment: @Tsyvarev `Note, that if your filesystem requires some device to be specified, then this device should be preliminary formatted (filled with the data in appropriate format).` how do I format it. I create device with mknod is there any command that I use to format it and what formatting a device means?

Comment: You have written the driver for some filesystem and ask me what that filesystem does and what it needs? Really? According to the name (`ramfs3`) and function `mount_nodev` called in `.mount` method, your filesystem works without device but with memory allocated in RAM. Probably, you should be able to mount a device with your filesystem with `mount -t ramfs3 <device> /fwd` command line. This line assumes that your driver is already loaded (with `insmod`) and `/fwd` directory (mount point) is already existed. Instead of `<device>` you could use any string, this string will be ignored.

Comment: @Tsyvarev just please let me know for block device do i need `mount_single` or `mount_nodev`. When I use `mount_nodev`,  then `mount` command gives me not valid block device. there is only one other option which is mount_subtree. and there really no documentation on these functions. Please tell if there is

Comment: On this page it say `mount_bdev: mount a filesystem residing on a block device` but in my fs.h file it is hard coded that it return error can't mount something

Comment: @tsyvarev I would use mount_bdev but in my system it's hard coded in fs.h to return error

Comment: if I define `CONFIG_BLOCK` in module file then only I can use mount_bdev which is for blockdevice its on google source listing that info

Comment: It seems you have a little understanding of what kernel module you are writing. I would suggest you to find some tutorial(example) about writing filesystems in Linux and follow that tutorial. After you will able to successfully compile and run that example, then you can try to modify different parts of code in that example. Writing a filesystem without any background is almost an impossible task.